# Problems in my Tex files when compiling tikzcircuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, circuitikz, debugging

I have been trying to compile my file that contains a tikzcircuit for few hours now (>6hours), on overleaf. The file compiles with no problem whatsoever when the circuitikz is commented. However, once I uncommented I get the error (Time out). I just don't get it. This is the circuit:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \begin{document}
            \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8]\draw
                \draw [short,*-](0,0)to(0,-0.1);
                (0,0)node[label={[font=\footnotesize]above:1}] {}] to
                \draw[short](8,2)to(8,0);
                            \draw[short](0,0)to(0,2);
                            \draw(0,-2)to[L,l=$L_1$,-*](0,0);
                            \draw[short](0,0)to(1,0)
                            to[C,l=$C_1$](1,-2);
                            \draw (1,0)to[L,l=$L_2$](4,0);
                            % \draw[short](4,0)to(4,0)
                            \draw(4,0)to [R,l=$R_1$,*-](4,-2);
                            \draw[short](4,0)to(4.1,0)
                            to[C,l=$C_2$](8,0);
                            \draw(8,0)to[R,l=$R_2$,*-](8,-2);
                            \draw(0,2)to[R,l=$R_3$](8,2);
                            \draw[short](0,-2)to(8,-2);
                            \draw(8,-2) node[ground]{};
                
                            {[anchor=south east] (0,0) node {1} (4,0) node {2} (8,0) node {3}}
                ; 
            \end{circuitikz}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I thought maybe it was Overleaf's server or whatever, so I chose to try to compile it on my computer latex.

```
 \documentclass{standalone}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

 \usepackage[compatibility]{circuitikzgit}
 \ctikzset{bipoles/length=.9cm}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
 \draw (0,0) to [resistor={name=R}] (0,2)
 to[diode={name=D}] (3,2);
 \draw (0,0) to[*R=$R_1$] (1.5,0) to[*Tnpn] (3,0)
 to[*D](3,2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

It doesn't compile either! Second step to debugg was to try an example from the [tikz documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikzmanual.pdf/0) (last example page 222), literally "copy-paste". To my surprise I get the following errors:

[image]

Is there something I am missing? I really don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: As always please extend your example into a full but minimal example taht can be copied and tested as is.

Comment: Exactly which example in the manual is this suppose to be?

Comment: @daleif Trying to see what's wrong with my Latex. The Manual Example is to be copied and tested as is. Whereas for mine -the first one- I need the packages. Give me one second please.

Comment: But what example is it? Page 222 of the link you provided does not resemple any of what you posted. Additionally, where is `short` defined?

Comment: @daleif, sorry forgot to paste it. There it is now. I have modified my answer.

Comment: @daleif short needn't be defined, or does it?

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`circuitikzgit.sty' not found.`  from your example

Comment: If I use circuitikz instead of circuitikzgit it runs without error in texlive 2022

Comment: Your first example has no document class and so can't be tested. (Incidentally you should use the `tikz` option if using `standalone` with tikz, better to test with `article` unless you specifically need `standalone`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added the documentclass. Thank you your remark, (>6hours is messing me up). I have been trying to run it with the article document class, to no avail. I will also check circuitikz instead of the git.

Comment: your first example gives error on line 8 `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.` because you have `\draw\draw [short,*-](0,0)to(0,-0.1);` with two `\draw`

Comment: If `short` is suppose to be a style defined somewhere then it probably needs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you get

`! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

From line 8 due to the double `\draw` on the first path

```
\draw
                \draw [short,*-](0,0)to(0,-0.1);
```

If you delete one of the `\draw` it rus without error but warns

```
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
...
```

as the path syntax is wrong in

`(0,0)node[label={[font=\footnotesize]above:1}] {}] to`

it has no leading `\draw` and no `;` But I don't know what you intended.

Comment: I was trying to name nodes, but the command didn't seem to work. Oh thank you for the ```\draw``` remark, my eyes are starting to fail me.

Comment: when I delete it and add ```{[anchor=south east] (0,0) node {1} (4,0) node {2} (8,0) node {3}}
   ; ``` it still doesn't name my nodes...

Comment: I think just by deleting the semicolon of the line before (```\draw(8,-2) node[ground]{}```), the nodes are named, although I really don't get why to be honest. What has the node naming to do with the GND?

Comment: @Wallflower `\draw(8,-2) node[ground]{};` is doing the following: 1) start to draw with normal line thickness; 2) move without stroking at (8,-2); 3) position a node with a shape named `ground` (which is a node-element provided by `circuitikz`) using its default anchor (`center`) at the current point. This node has no external name. To give a name to the node you can use   `node[ground](MY GROUND NAME){}`.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, apart from the infinite loop found by David Carlisle, you got the syntax for `circuitikz` wires wrong. `short` is a path-element style, and *must* be used as a style to a `to` command. Otherwise, scoping will be wrong, and everything can happen. Normally bad things would happen.

You can't use

```
\draw[short] (0,0) to (0,1);
```

the correct syntax is

```
\draw(0,0) to[short] (0,1);
```

About your second example, you are mixing `circuitikz` with the internal circuit library of Ti*k*Z. Although there is the compatibility mode flag, this is not recommended nor tested a lot. Don't do it.